# Error in .pmmlDataDictionary(field, transformed = transforms) : nmatrix.2 class is not supported for features

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science, pmml

How to convert r neural network model into `pmml` file? I used `pmml` package in `r`, but got an error:

```
nn_pmml <- pmml(mynn)

Error in .pmmlDataDictionary(field, transformed = transforms) : 
nmatrix.2 class is not supported for features. Supported classes: numeric, logical, factor.
```

The response variable (`Churn`) is binary, so to have classification model I set `softmax` parameter to `TRUE`

```
mynn <- nnet(Churn ~ ., data=trainNN,
         size=3, decay=1.0e-5, maxit=50, softmax = TRUE)
```

response variable `Churn` is of class `matrix` with 2 columns (corresponding to two categories), otherwise `nnet()` function throws an error:

```
Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) : 
'softmax = TRUE' requires at least two response categories
```

Just converting `Churn` into `factor` doesn't work...

So how to convert classification neural networks models from `r` into `pmml`?

Thanks!